# I get "STOP: 0x0000007E" BSOD every time I start windows

Tags: windows-7, bsod

2 days ago I bought a new computer and after installation of Windows and motherboard drivers I get a BSOD every time I start windows normally.

The motherboard is MSI z97 gaming 3.
I have tried reinstalling Windows and the drivers a couple of times, searching for the BSOD code in google and the result is that I cannot find out what's causing the error.
I don't use any OC and haven't found any thread about that particular error.

> *** STOP: 0x0000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000420, 0xFFFFF800031E8B8D, 0xFFFFF8800410E468, 0xFFFFF8800410DB90)

[image]

As the first thing after installation of Windows I installed the latest motherboard drivers and then installed all drivers that came on a cd with the MB.

My RAM is HyperX FURY DDR3-1866 16GB CL10 (HX318C10FBK2/16).

Comment: What is the BSoD error?

Comment: Does the BSOD occur with a fresh Windows installation before installing the motherboard drivers?

Comment: *** STOP 0x0000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000420, 0xFFFFF80031E8B8D, 0xFFFFF8800410E468, 0xFFFFF8800410DB90)

Comment: no, it doesnt happen on a fresh windows

Comment: All of them werent associated with my particular problem and there is plenty so i cant remember them

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: The problem is resolved
After following instructions of @TD.512 everything is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0x0000007E: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED A system thread
>   generated an exception which the error handler did not catch. There
>   are numerous individual causes for this problem, including hardware
>   incompatibility, a faulty device driver or system service, or some
>   software issues.

This is likely to be a driver issue or RAM fault. the first driver I'd look at is the sound card driver. It is usually the one to cause these problems.

source: http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/frequent-bsods-on-win7-x64-including-7e-error.171514/

Comment: I installed the drivers that were on a cd with me MB

Comment: The driver is Realtek HD Audio

Comment: did you try uninstalling all the drivers and starting with them one by one?

Comment: rebooting after each driver installation

Comment: No i didnt
I have installed the MB drivers and then the rest from the CD

Comment: try the one by one install. That will help you identify the driver that is causing issues, and if not that, try removing a stick of RAM and moving the RAM to different ports to test the RAM

Comment: Can i boot the pc from USB?
because i dont have the cd with windows right now

Comment: i tried to boot from usb but the pc starts normally
is it possible to install windows without cd?

Comment: did you press the Boot selection key? usually F11, F12 or similar. Also, is the USB bootable?

Comment: i dont really know
i just put the windows on pendrive and selected it as the boot device

Comment: Ill try to get the cd in an hour or two

Comment: I just installed windows, everything is right so far
I will install intel chipset drivers now